# Looking up values in two pandas data frames and create new columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, lookup, concatenation

I have two data frames in my problem.

df1

```
ID      Value
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C
```

df2:

```
ID      F_ID     S_ID
1       2        3
2       3        1
3       1        2
```

I want to create a column next to each ID column that will store the values looked up from df1. The output should look like this :

```
ID  ID_Value     F_ID  F_ID_Value   S_ID  S_ID_Value
1     A             2   B              3       C
2     B             3   C              1       A
3     C             1   A              2       B
```

Basically looking up from df1 and creating a new column to store these values.

Comment: Order is not important?

Comment: @jezrael: order is not important. but the question has already been answered!

Comment: yop, I ask because not match witch order of expected output, if no problem then OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on each column of `df2` with the value of `df1`.

```
s = df1.set_index('ID')['Value']
for col in df2.columns:
    df2[f'{col}_value'] = df2[col].map(s)
print (df2)
   ID  F_ID  S_ID ID_value F_ID_value S_ID_value
0   1     2     3        A          B          C
1   2     3     1        B          C          A
2   3     1     2        C          A          B
```

or with `apply` and `concat`

```
df_ = pd.concat([df2, df2.apply(lambda x: x.map(s)).add_prefix('_value')], axis=1)
df_ = df_.reindex(sorted(df_.columns), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If order is important (I realised not in comments) is necessary use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with enumerate and some maths:

```
s = df1.set_index('ID')['Value']

for i, col in enumerate(df2.columns, 1):
    df2.insert(i * 2 - 1, f'{col}_value', df2[col].map(s))
print (df2)
   ID ID_value  F_ID F_ID_value  S_ID S_ID_value
0   1        A     2          B     3          C
1   2        B     3          C     1          A
2   3        C     1          A     2          B
```